# worldwide Weather API for commercial use?

Tags: api, weather

I've been googling for weather API and most of them are for non-commercial use or US only.
Is there free (or low price) weather API that supports worldwide?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

check out [worldweatheronline](http://www.worldweatheronline.com/free-weather-feed.aspx)

Comment: no worries.I hope it will help you